# Display UserName only once in csv powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am having the below code which is giving me the list of ad groups a specific user is part of

```
Get-Content "C:\Automation Scripts\users.txt" | Get-ADUser | ForEach{
    $user = $_
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user
    $groups | %{ New-Object PSObject -Property @{ User = $user.SamAccountName; Group = $_.SamAccountName } }
} | Export-Csv "C:\Automation Scripts\User_Groups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

It is working fine and I am getting the result, but the result is coming like below

```
"User","Group"
"A92M7202822","Domain Users"
"A92M7202822","A92GS-505-Central Team Data"
"A92M7202822","A00GRP-AdminAccounts"
"A92A7803642","Protected Users"
"A92A7803642","A00GRP-AdminAccounts"
```

I need the result in csv like below

```
User,Group
A92M7202822,"Domain Users
A92GS-505-Central Team Data
A00GRP-AdminAccounts
A92GS-505-Ids-Analytics-Share-A92DFS
A92GS-505-Data-DSICF-DEV
A92GS-505-Data-DSICF-PRD
CFRGRP-FS-FR4000_SSgt_CFIDS_RW"
A92A7803642,"Domain Users
Protected Users
A00GRP-AdminAccounts"
```

One cell for user and next cell should have all the groups in it.

Please let me know what changes need to be done for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use New-Object, instead you can use PSCustomobject. Also, in your script you have used $user.samaccountname as values for both User and Groups. I have replaced group name value with name you may modify it.

```
$output = @()
$output += Get-Content "C:\Automation Scripts\users.txt" | Get-ADUser | ForEach{
    $user = $_
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user
    [PSCustomObject]@{
    'User'= $user.SamAccountName
    'Group' = $groups.Name
   }    
} 

$output | Export-Csv "C:\Automation Scripts\User_Groups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

And another efficient way of doing this is like:

```
$users = Get-Content "C:\Automation Scripts\users.txt"
$output = foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user

    foreach($group in $groups)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            User  = $user
            Group = $group.Name
        }
    }
}
$output | Export-Csv "C:\Automation Scripts\User_Groups.csv"  -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for response. for the 2nd solution I am getting the same output as before. multiple users and multiple ad group entries. for the first one I am getting like `"A92M7202822","System.Object[]"`